# Ajax issue only on externally facing server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, remote-server, publishing

We are using Ajax within a single page web application using Asp.Net web forms combined with Telerik. When a user clicks the grid, is should hide the grid within that UpdatePanel and show the sliders within another UpdatePanel.

The code works fine on localhost and our development server within our firewall; however, we receive the error below when we publish to our externally facing server:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null | MsAjaxJs?v=D6VN0fHlwFSIWjbVzi6mZyE9Ls-4LNrSSYVGRU46XF81:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gose.png)

When the user clicks the Telerik grid, it now does nothing and the error above is shown. Why is this error server dependent?

Comment: One of many generic client-side errors you will get when using AJAX and there is a server error.  Disable the AJAX temporarily and republish, chances are you will see the real error.

Comment: Thank you. That did lead to displaying the actual error.